# How can I do an order by of a field inside and another object?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="question in modal.data.questions | orderBy: number">
   <a data-ng-click="$parent.modal.selected=$index">Q{{ question.number }}</a>
</li>
```

Where number is a field in the questions object. When I check with the debugger I see two values of number 5 and 6. When it shows on the screen 6 is first and 5 second.

My problem is that the

is not repeating in order of the number. I have tried some different combinations. Can someone confirm my orderBy is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) takes an expression which can be the name of the field as **string**, you need to quote the `number` like this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="question in modal.data.questions | orderBy: 'number'">
```

> The expression can be a **string**: An Angular expression which evaluates to an object to order
>   by, such as 'name' to sort by a property called 'name'. Optionally
>   prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order
>   (for example, +name or -name).

Comment: THANK YOU !  I have been trying to figure this out for an hour or more. I will accept your answer !